# In lean 4, how do I refer to variables with names like `a✝`

Tags: lean4, beginner

When I have a tactic state that mentions a variable name like `a✝`, is there a way to refer to it? When I use this variable name in my code, it says it doesn't exist.

For example:

```
import Mathlib
example
  (a : Int)
  (b : Nat)
  (ha : a ≤ 0)
  (hb : 1 <= b)
  : (Int.div a b ≤ 0)
  := by
  induction a
  simp at ha
  rw [ha]
  simp
  unfold Int.div
  simp
  induction a✝  -- unknown identifier 'a'
```

This is the state just before the `induction a✝`:

```
1 goal
case negSucc
b: ℕ
hb: 1 ≤ b
a✝: ℕ
ha: Int.negSucc a✝ ≤ 0
⊢ 0 ≤ (↑a✝ + 1) / ↑b
```

I realize it might not make semantic sense to induct on `a✝` here, but I'd still like to know syntactically how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You <strike>don't</strike> can't :)

```
import Mathlib
example
  (a : Int)
  (b : Nat)
  (ha : a ≤ 0)
  (hb : 1 <= b)
  : (Int.div a b ≤ 0)
  := by
  induction a with
  | ofNat a =>
    simp at ha
    rw [ha]
    simp
  | negSucc a =>
    simp [Int.div]  --in my option this is better than unfold Int.div
    induction a with
    | zero => sorry
    | succ a iha => sorry
```

More seriously, they make it hard to type so that you explicitly name the variable.

Edit: My advice for how to get the `induction` syntax right.

1. Type `induction x` (where `x` is the variable you want to induct on).
2. Look at new subgoals and their case names, in this case `ofNat` and `negSucc`.
3. Type `| ofNat _ _ _ _ _ => _` and start deleting `_` on the right until Lean stops complaining.
4. Name those `_` with variable names.
5. Repeat starting at step 2 for the other subgoal branches.

Comment: Is there *actually* no way to do this, or is it just your preference not to? I'm a total beginner, so very often when using a new command I don't yet know how to force certain names. And it would be very helpful to have a fallback way to refer to the variables, instead of having an extra problem of "how do I make this new thing give names".

Comment: If the answer is "you can't say the names", please explicitly say you *can't* instead of "don't".

Comment: I don't know of a way.  Maybe there is.  Certainly this should be added to the cases where an error message about `✝` would be extremely helpful.

Comment: There is also the [rename_i](https://github.com/haruhisa-enomoto/mathlib4-all-tactics/blob/main/all-tactics.md#rename_i) tactic, but I agree it's much better to name the variables explicitly.