# In lean 4, how do I give names to variables when using `split`?

Tags: lean4, beginner

*Sort of related to [In lean 4, how do I refer to variables with names like `a✝`](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/in-lean-4-how-do-i-refer-to-variables-with-names-like-a.)*

When I use `split` to pull apart a `match`, I get a huge influx of variables. How do I name them so I can refer to them? (Should I be using split to pull apart match?)

````
import Mathlib

example
  (a : Int)
  (b c : Nat)
  (ha : 0 <= a)
  (hb : 1 <= b)
  : (Int.div a (Nat.succ b) ≤ Int.div a b)
  := by
  induction' b with d hd
  absurd hb
  simp
  induction d
  simp
  induction' a with a2 ha2
  simp
  simp [Int.div]
  split  -- adds variables "x✝¹", "x✝", "m✝", "n✝", "heq✝¹", "heq✝"
  sorry
  sorry
  sorry
  sorry
  sorry
  sorry
```
````

Comment: Does https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/2590/122 answer your question?

Comment: Actually, I guess it is a bit different.  I'll give another answer.

Comment: Also, I know you are coming here from the NNG and are confused, but I would read [the tactic chapter of TPIL4](https://lean-lang.org/theorem_proving_in_lean4/tactics.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` (or `next`) tactic to specify the subgoal and name the variables.  See the doc string for `split` for more information.  Here I used `case` with `induction` as well.

```
example
  (a : Int)
  (b c : Nat)
  (ha : 0 <= a)
  (hb : 1 <= b)
  : (Int.div a (Nat.succ b) ≤ Int.div a b)
  := by
  induction b
  case zero =>
    absurd hb
    simp
  case succ d hd =>
    induction d
    case zero =>
      simp
      induction a
      case ofNat a =>
        simp
        simp [Int.div] -- I don't think this is a good idea, but to illustrate how to do it...
        split
        case h_1 a b c d e f => sorry
        case h_2 a b c d e f => sorry
        case h_3 a b c d e f => sorry
        case h_4 a b c d e f => sorry
      case negSucc a => sorry
```